# Insert query depend on another table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-insert, mysql-select-db

Below are MySQL tables. I need to insert values from table A's ID column to Table B's ID_A column. Already existed values in ID_A should be ignored. So that in the below mentioned example IDs 1 to 3 from Table A should be ignored and IDs 4 to 10 should be inserted in table B. ID_X's value is constant i.e. 3.

What would be a single insert SQL query?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One straightforward option is to left join `A` with `B` and insert only those records from `A` which do not already appear in `B`.

```
INSERT INTO B (ID_A, ID_X)
SELECT A.ID, 3
FROM A LEFT JOIN B
   ON A.ID = B.ID_A
WHERE B.ID_A IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `unique index` on column `ID_A`, and then run query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_b
    SELECT      ID,
                3
        FROM    table_a;
```

This should add the missing rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TABLEB
(ID_A,ID_X)
SELECT
     ID,
     3
FROM TABLEA
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID_A FROM TABLEB)
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;)

```
insert into tableb (id_a, id_x)
select a.id as id_a, 3 as id_x from tablea a join tableb b on b.id_a <> a.id
```